# how to move a rotated of 90 deg text on the left bottom corner of the page?

Tags: margins, minipage, rotating

I would like the text on the bottom left corner of the page. Instead, the text is on the top side of the page. I am trying to move it down, I deleted \centering and I tried also other options I set \hspace*{3 cm} but nothing change. Could you help me please?
Here the code:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\smartqed  
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}
\vspace{1em}
    \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}


      %  \centering
        \rotatebox{90}{
            \begin{minipage}{0.8\textheight}
               \hspace*{3 cm}
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \footnotesize

\section{APPENDIX  }
\label{sec:5}
Here below the matrix when Dirichlet and Neumann boundary condition are set. H is a term included in the convective matrix coming from the convective boundary condition. 
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{ h \cdot \Delta \theta }{\rho \cdot c \cdot \Delta x}
\end{equation}

\nomenclature[A]{$b,g$}{ Fourier numbers for different materials \nomunit{}}


                \[
\begin{bmatrix}
T_{1} \\
T_{2} \\
T_{3} \\
... \\
T_{n-1}  \\
T_{n}
\end{bmatrix}^{v+1}
\quad
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1+2b+2H  & -2b  &   0  &  0   & 0    &  0   \\
-b       & 1+2b &  -b  &  0   & 0    &  0   \\
0        &  -b  & 1+2b &  -b  & 0    &  0   \\
...      & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  \\
0        &   0  &  0   &  -b  & 1+2b &  -b  \\
0        &   0  &  0   &   0  &  0   &  1
\end{bmatrix}^{inv}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
T_{1} \\
T_{2} \\
T_{3} \\
...   \\
T_{n-1}\\
T_{n}
\end{bmatrix}^{v}
\quad
+
\begin{bmatrix} 
1+2b+2H  & -2b  &   0  &  0   & 0    &  0  \\
-b       & 1+2b &  -b  &  0   & 0    &  0  \\
0        &  -b  & 1+2b &  -b  & 0    &  0  \\
...      & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ... \\
0        &   0  &  0   &  -g  & 1+2g &  -g  \\
0        &   0  &  0   &   0  &  0   &   1
\end{bmatrix}^{inv}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{2h\Delta \theta Tair}{\rho c \Delta x} \\
0 \\
0 \\
...   \\
0\\
60
\end{bmatrix}^{v}
\]
                \vspace*{\fill}
            \end{minipage}
        }
        %\captionof{figure}{Some Matrix}
        \label{eq:somematrix}
    \end{minipage}
%\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a few substitutions to get it to run on my system.  First, your matrix equation was too wide for even landscape, so I broke it into two lines.  Second, if you want the rotated box to be at the bottom left, you need to add `\vspace*{\fill)` before `\rotatebox`.  (BTW, `\vspace*{fill}` does nothing inside a normal minipage.)  Finally, I added a `\fbox` just to show the borders.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{article}       % onecolumn (second format)
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

%\smartqed  
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
    \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}


      %  \centering
        \rotatebox{90}{\fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}{0.8\textheight}
               \hspace*{3 cm}
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \footnotesize

\section{APPENDIX  }
\label{sec:5}
Here below the matrix when Dirichlet and Neumann boundary condition are set. H is a term included in the convective matrix coming from the convective boundary condition. 
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{ h \cdot \Delta \theta }{\rho \cdot c \cdot \Delta x}
\end{equation}

\nomenclature[A]{$b,g$}{ Fourier numbers for different materials \nomunit{}}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
T_{1} \\
T_{2} \\
T_{3} \\
... \\
T_{n-1}  \\
T_{n}
\end{bmatrix}^{v+1}
\quad
=&
\begin{bmatrix} 
1+2b+2H  & -2b  &   0  &  0   & 0    &  0   \\
-b       & 1+2b &  -b  &  0   & 0    &  0   \\
0        &  -b  & 1+2b &  -b  & 0    &  0   \\
...      & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  \\
0        &   0  &  0   &  -b  & 1+2b &  -b  \\
0        &   0  &  0   &   0  &  0   &  1
\end{bmatrix}^{inv}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
T_{1} \\
T_{2} \\
T_{3} \\
...   \\
T_{n-1}\\
T_{n}
\end{bmatrix}^{v}
\\ &\quad+
\begin{bmatrix} 
1+2b+2H  & -2b  &   0  &  0   & 0    &  0  \\
-b       & 1+2b &  -b  &  0   & 0    &  0  \\
0        &  -b  & 1+2b &  -b  & 0    &  0  \\
...      & ...  & ...  & ...  & ...  & ... \\
0        &   0  &  0   &  -g  & 1+2g &  -g  \\
0        &   0  &  0   &   0  &  0   &   1
\end{bmatrix}^{inv}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{2h\Delta \theta Tair}{\rho c \Delta x} \\
0 \\
0 \\
...   \\
0\\
60
\end{bmatrix}^{v}
\end{align*}
                %\vspace*{\fill}
            \end{minipage}
        }}
        %\captionof{figure}{Some Matrix}
        \label{eq:somematrix}
    \end{minipage}
%\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok thanks you are right the formula with the matrices were too long.  Now I have decided to keep the pdf page and text straight since the matrices is braked in half. Unfortunately I cannot get how to make it straight normally.